# Matrix norm question

Tags: matrices

Let $A^*$ denote the complex conjugate transpose of a matrix $A$. In the Euclidean norm, if

$$||A^*A+AA^*||=||A^*A||$$

does it imply that $AA^*=0$. If not, could you give a counter-example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a counterexample, consider
$$
A:=\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}.
$$

Comment: Thank you. This is a part of an other problem, which I posted here: [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1129018/matrix-norm-relation-between-aa-and-aa).