# Matrix norm relation between $A^*A$ and $AA^*$

Tags: matrices

Let $A^*$ denote the complex conjugate transpose of a matrix $A$. In the Euclidean norm, if

$$||A^*A+AA^*||=||A^*A||$$

does this imply that

$$||A^*A+AA^*||=||A^*A-AA^*||$$

Related question: [Matrix norm question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1128930/matrix-norm-question/1128952#1128952)

Comment: What do you mean by "Euclidean norm"? Do you mean the operator norm induced by the standard euclidean norm or do you mean the Frobenius norm?

Comment: The operator norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

1. If $B$ is Hermitian then $\|B\|=\sup_{\|v\|=1}|tr(Bv\overline{v}^t)|$. Also,  $tr(A^*Av\overline{v}^t)\geq0$ and if $tr(A^*Av\overline{v}^t)=0$ then $Av=0$.
2. Use item 1 to prove that $\|AA^*-A^*A\|\leq\|AA^*+A^*A\|$
3. Use item 1 and $\|AA^*+A^*A\|=\|AA^*\|$ to prove that if $AA^*v=\|AA^*\|v$ then $A^*Av=0$.

Finally, $(AA^*-A^*A)v=\|AA^*\|v$. Thus, $\|AA^*-A^*A\| \geq \|AA ^*\|=\|AA^*+A^*A\|$.

So $\|AA^*-A^*A\|=\|AA^*+A^*A\|$.

Comment: I can prove the four statements you've set up, but I'm afraid I don't follow from "Finally, ..." There seems to be a parenthesis missing?

Comment: Do you mean $(AA^*-A^*A)(v-w)=\|AA^*\|(v-w)$?

Comment: Notice that $\|AA^*\|$ is an eigenvalue of $AA^*-A^*A$. Thus, $\|AA^*-A^*A\|\geq\|AA^*\|$.

Comment: Yes, that's the one.

Comment: You are right. I made a mistake.

Comment: It is easy to fix

Comment: I believe it is fixed now.